# Unable to run more than one grafana pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, grafana

We have set up our own openshift cluster . We are able to bring up applications running on one pod but when we tried to scale up the application to 2 or more pods , it fails everytime with "CrashPullBackOff" error.

Debugging the logs gives permission denied for certain folders. If had this been the case neither of the pods should have been running . But we can run only one pod at max . One of the assumption we have is running pod run as user "grafana" while scaling up the pods results in user "root" . Can we control this behavior?

below is our dockerfile content

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest
USER root

COPY data/. /var/lib/grafana/
COPY config/. /usr/share/grafana/conf/

RUN chown -R grafana:grafana "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING" && \
    chmod -R 777 "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"

USER grafana
```

We should be able to scale up applications and run more than one pods . Please help since this has been bugging us a lot and no solution seems available

Comment: Are you using PersitentVolumes? If both pods are accessing a ReadWriteOnce volume you could be in trouble..

Comment: We are not using any PV for grafana . it just witches over to root user when we trying to run one more replica . This is the case with other applications too